# Executing bash strings using scala.sys.process

Tags: bash, scala

I recently discovered `sys.process` package in Scala, and was amused by its power.

But when I try to combine it with bash pipes and backticks, I get stuck.

This obviously doesn't work:

```
scala> "echo `date`" !!
res0: String = "
"`date`
"
```

I tried to use the bash executable to get the desired behavior:

```
scala> "bash -e echo `date`" !!
/bin/echo: /bin/echo: cannot execute binary file
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 126
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

```
scala> "bash -ic 'echo `date`'" !!
`date`': unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
`date`': syntax error: unexpected end of file
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 1
```

Comment: Informative example, but I hope you realise you don't need bash at all for this: `Seq("date")!!`

Comment: @ToddOwen - sure, that was just for example purposes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're doing multiple things wrong actually. You should be using the -c option of bash and you should be using a Seq[String] with each parameter to bash in its own String, or the scala library will just split the String at every space character. (This is why Rex Kerr's solution doesn't work.)

```
scala> import sys.process.stringSeqToProcess
import sys.process.stringSeqToProcess

scala> Seq("bash", "-c", "echo `date`")!!
res20: String = 
"Sun Dec 4 16:40:04 CET 2011
"
```

Comment: Good point about the `Seq` version.  I actually used that one instead, since I always do, and never checked the single-string version!

Comment: Here is another example executing a script and with args to follow.

IE: 
test.sh 
echo $1
scala>
Seq("/somePath/test.sh"," HI")!

credit due to here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039167/scala-system-process-and-whitespace