# Scala System Process and whitespace

Tags: scala, process, system

I am attempting to issue a system command to run the mri_convert of FreeSurfer.  You don't really need to understand what mri_convert is, as much as you have to understand how the processes are transfered from scala to the system.  The code works for the most part, but when I attempt to send a file path with spaces it breaks (even after I replace the spaces with `\`).  I'll post my code below and then the output from using a file without directory containing a space in its path, and then from a file path with a directory with a space.

```
def executeAll(): Boolean = {
  while (dataBuf.length != 0) {
    val dir = directory + "subjects/" + dataBuf.first.subjectID + "/mri/orig"
    val expr = """\s+""".r  
    val path = expr.replaceAllIn((dataBuf.first.path), """\\ """)
    val folder = new File(dir)
    val execute = freesurfer + """bin/mri_convert -it dicom -ot mgz -ii """ + path + """ -oi """ + dir + """/001.mgz"""
    if (folder.mkdirs()) {
      val command = Process(execute, folder, ("FREESURFER_HOME", freesurfer))
      val exitCode = command.!
      println(command.toString())
    }
    dataBuf.remove(dataBuf.indexOf(dataBuf.first))
  }
  println("DONE")
  dataListView.listData = dataBuf
  true
}
```

Output without directory with space:

```
val path = /Applications/freesurfer/bin/mri_convert -it dicom -ot mgz -ii /Volumes/N/0110547/2008-05-24/data/BIRNSequence_4/IM-0003-0001.dcm -oi /Users/michael/Documents/subjects/dadasd/mri/orig/001.mgz 

[/Applications/freesurfer/bin/mri_convert, -it, dicom, -ot, mgz, -ii, /Volumes/N/0110547/2008-05-24/data/BIRNSequence_4/IM-0003-0001.dcm, -oi, /Users/michael/Documents/subjects/dadasd/mri/orig/001.mgz]
```

Output directory with space:

```
val path = /Applications/freesurfer/bin/mri_convert -it dicom -ot mgz -ii /Volumes/N/0110547/2005-07-31/this\ is\ the\ data/AXBIRN_4/IM-0004-0001.dcm -oi /Users/michael/Documents/subjects/adsfsdf/mri/orig/001.mgz 

mri_convert: extra arguments ("the\" and following)
 [/Applications/freesurfer/bin/mri_convert, -it, dicom, -ot, mgz, -ii, /Volumes/N/0110547/2005-07-31/this\, is\, the\, data/AXBIRN_4/IM-0004-0001.dcm, -oi, /Users/michael/Documents/subjects/adsfsdf/mri/orig/001.mgz]
```

I think it has to do with the fact that the argument passed to the system breaks the path with  a space in the directory as seen in the brackets.  Therefore, I believe that there is something funny going on with how my process is created.  More importantly, in each situation if I cut and paste the val of path into terminal, the mri_convert program executes as expected.

Thanks in advance, and please let me know if more detail is required.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest creating your process from a sequence of the arguments instead of trying to get something downstream to parse them correctly.  To do that you use the [stringSeqToProcess](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/sys/process/package.html#stringSeqToProcess%28Seq%5bString%5d%29%3aProcessBuilder) implicit method.

I created a shell script that prints out each of its arguments on a separate line.  For good measure I put a space in the path to the script.  I then was able to execute it from Scala:

```
import scala.sys.process._
Seq("/home/lwickland/sp ace/script.sh", "a1", "/path/with a/sp ace", "c")!
```

The shell script saw the argument containing spaces as a single item.

```
Arg: a1
Arg: /path/with a/sp ace
Arg: c
```

I'd suggest trying to modify your code to be like:

```
def executeAll(): Boolean = {
  while (dataBuf.length != 0) {
    val dir = directory + "subjects/" + dataBuf.first.subjectID + "/mri/orig"
    val folder = new File(dir)
    val execute = Seq("sh", freesurfer + "bin/mri_convert", "-it", "dicom", "-ot", "mgz", "-ii", path, "-oi", dir +"/001.mgz")
    if (folder.mkdirs()) {
      val command = Process(execute, folder, ("FREESURFER_HOME", freesurfer))
      val exitCode = command.!
      println(command.toString())
    }
    dataBuf.remove(dataBuf.indexOf(dataBuf.first))
  }
  println("DONE")
  dataListView.listData = dataBuf
  true
}
```

Please let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: Would you be willing to post the code that you're using to try this approach?

Comment: I was able to run a shell script which wasn't marked executable by adding a "sh" as the first argument in the Seq().  `Seq("sh", "/home/lwickland/sp ace/script.sh", "a1", "/path/with a/sp ace", "c")!`  Of course for that to work, you'd have to "sh" in your path.  If it's not, you'll have to put something like "/bin/sh" in there.

Comment: Here's the new problem: the file path with the backslashes (for spaces) is broken up into multiple arguments when sent as an argument to the .sh file.  The sequence being passed is as follows: [/Users/michael/Desktop/shell.sh, /Users/michael/Documents/subjects/34242/mri/orig/001.mgz, /Volumes/NOWAK/0110547/2005-07-31/this\, is\, the\, data/AXBIRN_4/IM-0004-0001.dcm]

Comment: At this point, I'm not sure exactly what you're trying.  Do you have something like what I appended to my answer above?  Specifically, I don't think you need to do any backslash replacement.  Also, are you creating the Process with a first argument like `val execute = Seq("sh", freesurfer + "bin/mri_convert", "-it", "dicom", "-ot", "mgz", "-ii", path, "-oi", dir +"/001.mgz")`?

Comment: Leif, you're right.  You actually don't need to do any backslash replacement if you use the method that you specified.  Thanks for your help, it's now working!!