# How measure time stolen from virtual machine, in Scala/Java?

Tags: java, linux, performance, scala, amazon-ec2

I'm running a Play Framework Scala application in a JVM on an Amazon EC2 micro instance. The application sometimes indexes lots of text. However, if the virtual machine's CPU is constantly under high load, the hypervisor punishes the virtual machine by stealing time from it and giving to other virtual machines managed by that hypervisor.

I'm thinking about measuring the amount of time currently stolen, and if it's too high (above e.g. 5%) then I'll pause indexing, for a while.
stuff
Questions:

1. Is this at all a good idea? (Is it crazy? Or is there some better approach?)
2. How do I measure time stolen, from Scala / Java?

   Currently I'm thinking about doing an external process call ([e.g. `Seq("bash", "-c", "echo` date`")!!`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8376401/694469) to `vmstat` or `/proc/stat` and parse the output, and find the time stolen. But this could be error prone? What if e.g. a new version of `vmstat` outputs data in another format. I guess, however, that the output of `/proc/stat` will never change in a non-backwards compatible manner. (?)

All this doesn't need to work on Windows. Only flavors of Linux, e.g. Ubuntu and CentOS. And if the external process call fails, I'd simply return Scala's `None` instead of `Some(percentage)`.

**Update:** I found a library named Sigar with [a function `getStolen`](http://www.hyperic.com/support/docs/sigar/org/hyperic/sigar/Cpu.html#getStolen()http://www.hyperic.com/support/docs/sigar/org/hyperic/sigar/CpuPerc.html#getStolen%28%29) that might be appropriate. It returns a `double` that represents "*Total system cpu involuntary wait time*" — but in what units? And I wonder if it's unfortunately an aggregated total since the application started. Anyway here's someone actually using it to print the stolen time: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1301532

Answer (score 2):

I doubt these tools would be virtual machine aware.

I suggest polling System.nanoTime() periodically and when you see a jump in time, your thread was not running. You could even do something like jHiccup which just waits for a milli-second and times how long that took.

Note:  this can show very poor results even if the box is idle for virtual machines, so you have to tune it for your machine.

Comment: Thanks, interesting suggestions to poll nanoTime or use jHiccup. If I use jHiccup (for example), I suppose not only issues with stolen time would be mitigated, but also other things, e.g. if there was excessive swapping going on, then jHiccup would notice this, and the server could avoid indexing pages, until there was less swapping.

Comment: I think `vmstat` is indeed virtual machine aware? I found this in `man vmstat`, about the `st` column: *"st: Time stolen from a virtual machine. Prior to Linux 2.6.11, unknown."*

Answer (score 1):

When cpu has multiple cores `nanoTime` doesn't give cpu consumption. JVM has a tool [MXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html) that can help to determine actual cpu usage. I think `mxBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime()` can be used for the purpose. At least you can try

```
@tailrec
def working {
  val startCpu = mxBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime
  val startRealTime = System.nanoTime
  `do some work`
  val deltaCpu = mxBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime - startCpu
  val deltaRealTime = System.nanoTime - startRealTime
  val percentage = 100.0*deltaCpu/deltaRealTime
  if(percentage>5.0) suspend else working
}
```