# Providing Quoted Parameters to scala.sys.process Processes

Tags: linux, scala, email

I am using the `scala.sys.process` package to dispatch mail commands to a linux command line from within a scala application:

```
val emailList = "foo@nonExistentEntity.com,bar@nonExistentEntity.com"

val emailFile = "/home/localUser/localFile.txt"

import scala.sys.process._

(("cat " + emailFile) #| ("mail -s EmailSubject " + emailList)) !
```

So far so good.  However, if I want an email subject that contains spaces the mail man file states

> -s subject
>          Specify subject on command line ... be careful to quote subjects containing spaces.

When I try to wrap my subject in quotes and send that to mail:

```
val emailSubject = " \"A Spaceful Email Subject\" "

(("cat " + emailFile) #| ("mail -s" + emailSubject + emailList)) !
```

I get an error:

> ect"... Unbalanced '"'

So, how does one provide quoted paramaeters to processes using `scala.sys.process`?

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: Try to use Seq of strings instead of concatenation. See here: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.sys.process.package

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376193/executing-bash-strings-using-scala-sys-process

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247653/using-scala-sys-process-with-curl-single-quotes-and-white-space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `scala.sys.process` you can also use `Seq` to package up an executable with arguments that can have arbitrary spaces, newlines, etc.

Consider:

```
val emailSubject = "A Spaceful Email Subject"

(s"cat $emailFile" #| Seq("mail", "-s", emailSubject, emailList)).!
```

You can also see an example of this in [Scala 2.11.7 scaladocs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.sys.process.package)